# Android ADT ( 4.3) XML EDitor : Errror parsing XML: not well-formed ( invalid token)

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I actually don't understand why the editor is raising this error, in my main_activity.xml file for the

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backgroundImageView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/background" >
        </ImageView>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does it give you a line?

Comment: at where you got this???

Comment: eclipse doesn't show errors to me - maybe try to restart eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Add a newline character (\n) at the end of file.